# hibernate resultset and mapping confusion

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, mappings

I was having a problem in getting result through hibernate. 
I have four tables SnsUser, Participant, Interaction, Content;
SnsUser & Interaction has many-2-many relationship and Interaction and Content has many-2-one.
(SnsUser and Interation got Set of Participant in there mapping classes, hibernate does for many-2-many)

when I run HQL like

```
from SnsUser s join fetch s.participants p join fetch p.interaction i join fetch i.content c where s.blessUid=1
```

(returning List(SnsUser) list)

it gives me let say 10 rows and in each row (i.e. SnsUser) has 10 rows as Participant.

But when i run like a HQL like

```
from Participant p join fetch p.snsUser s join fetch p.interaction i join fetch i.content c where s.blessUid=1
```

it gives me 10 rows and i can get the relevant SnsUser from it.  BUT
when i look at the actual sql query it is same for the both. Why it behaves like this... ?

answers would be appreciated.
al

Answer (score 0):

I'm skeptic, both queries shouldn't be the same (one should be performed against the `SnsUser` table and the other should be performed against the `Participant` table).

And because I only trust what I see, I won't change my mind until you show the generated queries (and the mapping allowing to fully understand the model).

Comment: yea. i should have said similar. the join conditions are same. so the point is that would i always get Set populated when i would run from SnsUser?

Comment: @user330281: I need the mapping and object model to comment further.